# Power tower made of $2$s and $3$s: too high, too soon?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, recurrences

A power tower of a number $x$ is typified by

$$ x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}}}}}}.$$

Here, however, we take the liberty of referring to the set $T$ of "$\{2,3\}$-power towers"; i.e., numbers

$$x_1^{x_2^{x_3^{ \cdots\cdots^{x_k}}}},$$

where each $x_h$ is $2$ or $3,$ and $k \geq 2.$  Let $T_2$ be the subset of $T$ consisting of towers rising from $x_1=2.$  Let $R$ be the sequence of ranks of towers in $T_2$ when all the towers in $T$ are jointly ranked. For example, $7 \in R$ means that the $7$th smallest element in $T$ is a power of $2$, not of $3$. (The term *jointly ranked* is borrowed from statistics: if the numbers in two or more sets are combined and arranged in nondecreasing order, they are said to be jointly ranked.)

The first $15$ terms of $R$ are $$1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29.$$  What are the next terms?

Note that $T$ can be obtained recursively from $t_2 = \{2^2,2^3,3^2,3^3\}$ by defining

$$t_n =2^{t_{n-1}} \cup 3^{t_{n-1}}$$

for $n \geq 3;$  then $T$ is the union of the sets $t_n$ for $n \geq 2.$

For a top-first version of the problem, change $x_1=2$ to $x_k=2,$ where $k$ is the height of the tower.  Then the first $17$ terms are $$1,3,4,6,10,11,12,15,16,19,20,23,24,25,26,27,28,\ldots.$$  Here, too, the question is: what are the next terms?

Added later:  Thanks, Yaakov, you are right, so my question is, what are the positions of the numbers in $T_2$ in the sequence in the sequence $(1,2,3,\ldots)$.  I have the first $30$ positions (or ranks) and would like to see a method for finding more terms.

It may help to see a list of the first $20$ towers ranked:

$$4 = 2^2$$
$$8 = 2^3$$
$$9 = 3^2$$
$$16 = 2^{2^{2}}$$
$$27 = 3^3$$
$$81 = 3^{2^{2}}$$
$$256 = 2^{2^{3}}$$
$$512 = 2^{3^{2}}$$
$$6561 = 3^{2^{3}}$$
$$19683 = 3^{3^{2}}$$ 
Continuing with tuple notation instead of tower notation:
$(2,2,2,2), (3,2,2,2), (2,3,3), (3,3,3), (2,3,2,2), (3,3,2,2), (2,2,2,3), (3,2,2,3), (2,2,3,2), (3,2,3,2), (2,3,2,3).$

My method, so far, has been by computer sort, which reaches overflow pretty quickly.  Surely there must be a more insightful method.  A related question:  what is the position (or rank) of $(2,2,2,2,2,2)?$

Comment: What does *jointly ranked* mean?

Comment: Jointly ranked means arranged in increasing order:  $t_2 = \{4,8,16,256,\ldots\}$ and $t_3 = \{9,27,81,\ldots\},$ so that the joint ranking is $(4,8,9,16,27,81,256,\ldots).$

Comment: I think your setting is quite confusing as you consider the elements of $T$ both as number and as sequences of numbers. $t_2$ is an element of what? It would be helpful to distinguish sets of sequences and sets of numbers even if they are in bijection.

Comment: I think there are just 2 sets of numbers $T_2$ and $T_3$ and $T_2\sqcup T_3=T$. Then $T_2$-ranks $\sqcup$ $T_3$-ranks $=\{1,2,3,4,5\dots\}$.

Comment: $8=2^2$? $9=2^3$??

Comment: I find a certain rough affinity of this question with my question on math.SE about how to order the numbers in the googol-stack-bang-plex hierarchy: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/72646/413

Comment: $512=2^{3^3} $?

Comment: I shall never get it why we do not begin our indexing $k=1$ at the ***top*** of the power tower, from where we ***begin*** our evaluation, and why everywhere around the indexing begins at the bottom, which shall become the ***last*** coefficient involved in our evaluation...

Comment: See my comment to Taneli Huuskonen's answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $s_1=2^2$, $s_2=2^3$, $s_3=3^2$ and so on. For $i\ge 5$, it holds that $s_{i+1}\ge 2s_i$. This can be proved by induction. Then $s_{2i+3}=2^{s_i}$ and $s_{2i+4}=3^{s_i}$. In particular, all the remaining elements of $R$ are precisely the odd numbers larger than the ones shown, and the solution of the top-first version of the problem consists of sequences of consecutive numbers doubling in length. The rank of $(2,2,2,2,2,2)$ can be found out simply by enumerating the sequences up to it.

Comment: This argument can be extended to completely settle the problem: if two towers have the same length, their relative ranking is determined only by the top $3$ terms; if the towers have different length, the longer one has higher ranking **unless** the lengths differ by $1$ and the top of the longer tower is  $2^{2^2}$, while the top of the shorter is $3^3$.

Comment: I should add - if the lengths are the same and and the top 3 elements also are the same, then the comparison is based at the 4th element, then 5th and so on, top-down.